# Which is the correct flow to get current user's groups from Microsoft graph?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Hi I am implementing Groups based authorization to my web api. I have client application swagger. Through swagger I am logging in and calling web api. In web api I want to implement groups based authorization through Microsoft graph. When I logging through swagger I will get one token and I am passing to my webapi. If I am not wrong, Now I required one token to call Microsoft graph. So can I use same token to call microsoft graph? I confused my self and implemented client credential flow. Client credential flow will get token for the app(here user signed in token has nothing to do).

```
   public static async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphServiceClient()
        {
            // Get Access Token and Microsoft Graph Client using access token and microsoft graph v1.0 endpoint
            var delegateAuthProvider = await GetAuthProvider();
            // Initializing the GraphServiceClient
            graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(graphAPIEndpoint, delegateAuthProvider);

            return graphClient;
        }


        private static async Task<IAuthenticationProvider> GetAuthProvider()
        {
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

            // ADAL includes an in memory cache, so this call will only send a message to the server if the cached token is expired.
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResource, clientCred).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

            var delegateAuthProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token.ToString());
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });

            return delegateAuthProvider;
        }
```

Below code will return all the groups.

```
GraphServiceClient client = await MicrosoftGraphClient.GetGraphServiceClient();
 var groupList = await client.Groups.Request().GetAsync();
```

but my requirement is to get current signed in users group. So can someone help me which flow I should use and In the above code only Is it possible to get current users group? Can someone help me in understanding these and implement correctly? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a chance to look into my answer? Any updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have discussed before, you should call Microsoft Graph API from your webapi app.

So you should not use the same access token to call Microsoft Graph. You should specfy the Microsoft Graph endpoint (https://graph.microsoft.com) as the resource when you request a new access token to Microsoft Graph.

Secondly, client credential flow means app-only permission (without user). So if there is no signed in user, how could we get user's groups?

You should consider using [AcquireTokenAsync(String, ClientAssertion, UserAssertion)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_AuthenticationContext_AcquireTokenAsync_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_UserAssertion_).

After that, using the following code to get the signed in user's groups.

```
GraphServiceClient client = await MicrosoftGraphClient.GetGraphServiceClient();
var memberOf = await graphClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();
```